# Why is python printing weird results while using the nested loop here?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, nested-loops

I was given an array of strings and I want to split each of the individual strings into separate characters and store them in a separate 2-D array. I wrote the following code:-

```
# The given array
grid = ['1112', '1912', '1892', '1234']

# Creating a new 2D array
mat = [[None]*len(grid)]*len(grid)
for i in range(0,len(grid)):
    for j in range(0,len(grid)):
        mat[i][j] = grid[i][j]
print(mat)
```

But doing this gives weird values in my two-dimensional array, *mat*. Each of the row of the 2D array *mat* gets printed as ['1','2','3','4'] but this should be the value of the last row only.

I shall be thankful if someone could answer my query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
mat = [[None]*len(grid)]*len(grid)
```

This statement is creating a relational 2D array (matrix), so whenever you are updating a line, it will update all the other lines.

You should be using this to create an empty 2D array:

```py
mat = [[None for i in len(grid)] for j in range(len(grid))]
```

As @marc commented, you can also pass one list comprehension as width = height here

```py
mat = [[None]*len(grid) for _ in range(len(grid))]
```

Comment: You could safely skip one of the list comprehension steps and use `mat = [[None]*len(grid) for i in range(len(grid)]`.

Comment: @Marc Ah yeah, I will add it alongside, if they later need a matrix with a width different from the height, they would still need to do 2 list comprehensions

Answer (score 1):

The multiplication to list makes the same reference in memory, code fixed as following:

```py
# The given array
grid = ['1112', '1912', '1892', '1234']

# Creating a new 2D array
# mat = [[None]*len(grid)]*len(grid)
mat = []
for i in range(len(grid)):
    t = []
    for j in range(len(grid)):
        t.append(None)
    mat.append(t)

for i in range(0,len(grid)):
    for j in range(0,len(grid)):
        mat[i][j] = grid[i][j]
print(mat)
```

Comment: This would work but is longer to process than my answer, with list comprehension, which is also more readable

Answer (score 1):

I have to agree this is easy to get confused in this problem.

Let's say `len(grid)` = 2, so we get `mat = [[None]*2]*2`

Here `mat[0]` points to the same pobject of `mat[1]`, because `*2` is giving two pointers which pointing to the same array. You can use `for _ in range(2)` instead to create two different objects - `[[None]*len(grid) for _ in range(len(grid))]`

We can use `id` to print the object's address to verify:

```py
>>> mat = [[None]*2]*2
>>> id(mat[0])
76447616
>>> id(mat[1])
76447616
>>> grid = [0, 0]
>>> x = [[None]*len(grid) for _ in range(len(grid))]
>>> id(x[0])
76457744
>>> id(x[1])
76391968
```